# Single makefile to build multiple subdirectories

Tags: javascript, makefile

So inspired by http://www.olioapps.com/blog/the-lost-art-of-the-makefile/ I wanted to try to build a repo of several JS projects using make.

What I'm trying to do initially is just the rule to run `yarn install` whenever either `package.json` or `yarn.lock` changes. The rule if it's just a static rule is explained in the link and is just

```
node_modules: package.json yarn.lock
    yarn install
```

However I'm trying to do a similar rule that runs for multiple projects.

I have a directory structure like similar to this:

```
Makefile
rocks/js/projectA/package.json
rocks/js/projectA/yarn.lock
rocks/js/projectB/package.json
rocks/js/projectB/yarn.lock
...
```

And so forth with several projects. I've tried to use static pattern rules to write this out, but so far have failed quite miserably. What my Makefile looks like currently is

```
js_rocks = $(addprefix rocks/js/,$(shell ls rocks/js))

%/node_modules: %/package.json %/yarn.lock
    cd $(dir $@) && yarn install

$(js_rocks): %: %/node_modules

all: $(js_rocks)

.PHONY: all
```

This however only seems to detect and run for the first project in the list.

Comment: Which make are you using? GNU make, cmake, etc. Altho they have a common core, each has variations that are not compatible.

Comment: GNU Make 3.81 (on MacOS if it makes a difference)

Comment: In that case, I would replace the `shell ls` with the wildcard function: `js_rocks = $(wildcard rocks/js/*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the main problem was not really in the targets themselves, but in the fact that I had misunderstood make's default target to always be `all` whereas it is actually always the first target (thank you @shawnhcorey).

So with the feedback I got and a bit more reading up on make, this is the Makefile I have now which can run `yarn install` for all my sub-projects :)

```
js_rocks = $(wildcard rocks/js/*)
node_modules = $(addsuffix /node_modules,$(js_rocks))

all: $(node_modules)

clean:
    rm -rf $(node_modules)

$(node_modules): %/node_modules: %/package.json %/yarn.lock
    cd $*; yarn install

.PHONY: all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
%/node_modules: %/package.json %/yarn.lock
    cd $(dir $@) && ( yarn install ; cd - )
```

After the first one, the current directory is left in the node_modules directory. From there, `make` cannot find any more targets.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to change anything. The rule is still only triggered on the first project

Comment: Hmm I seem to have to little knowledge about make. So the rules doesn't run for everything when I just run `make` (which I expected to run the `all` target). However if I move the `all` target above the other targets I can get it to work and running for all the directories

Comment: @jsfr `make` with no arguments makes the first target in the makefile. Usually "all" is the first target.

Comment: yeah so I was missing this detail, from the explanations I read it was that the default target would always be `all` if it was available.